# Transition functions of toric projective bundle (Proposition in [Cox, Toric Varieties])

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry, tropical-geometry

My reference: David Cox's "Toric Varieties"

My question is the proof of **Proposition 7.3.3.**

> **Proposition 7.3.3.**
>   The cones {$\sigma_i$ | $\sigma \in \Sigma$, $i = 0,\dots,r$} and their faces form a fan $\Sigma_{\mathcal{E}}$ in $N_{\mathbb{R}} \times \overline{N}_{\mathbb{R}}$ whose toric variety $X_\mathcal{E}$ is the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$.

I already proved the first part, that is, $X_\mathcal{E}$ is a fibration over $X_{\Sigma}$ with fiber $\mathbb(P)^r$.

That is, \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
p^{-1}(U_{\sigma}) \simeq & \ U_{\sigma} \times X_{\Sigma_{\theta} , N_{\theta}}\\
\simeq & \ U_{\sigma} \times X_{\Sigma_{\theta} , \overline{N}}\\
\simeq & \ U_{\sigma} \times \mathbb{P}^r
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

where everything comes from the following short exact sequence and splitting theorem of fans:

\begin{equation*}
0\longrightarrow N_{\theta} = \ker(\overline{p}) \longrightarrow N \times \overline{N} \xrightarrow{\overline{p}} N \longrightarrow 0
\end{equation*}

> **My Question**
>
> I don't know how to prove the second part in the proof:
>
> *"Furthermore, working over an affine open subset of $X_{\Sigma}$, one sees that $X_{\Sigma}$ is obtained from $V_\mathcal{E}$ by the process described in 7.0."*
>
> How do I prove that? What should I check? And the author only say that "leave details as exercise", but the exercise is just "Complete the proposition 7.3.3". So, I have no idea to check this argument.
>
> Thank you for your help!